# NameError: Uninitialized constant Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

When I try to run any command that uses the Twitter API in the ruby console, I get the error `NameError: uninitialized constant Twitter`.

I have named this `twitterFeed.rb` because I read that it should not be named `twitter.rb`. This file is placed in my `config/initializers` folder. I have ran `bundle install` already, and the line `gem 'twitter', '~> 6.2'` is in my gem file.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'twitter'
require 'json'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
 config.consumer_key = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
 config.consumer_secret = ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
 config.access_token = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
 config.access_token_secret = ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
end
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `twitter.rb` in your `$LOAD_PATH`? It's possible you have an empty `twitter.rb` from your earlier experiments.

Comment: Note that filenames should be all lower-case by tradition: `twitter_feed.rb` is preferable to what you have there.

Comment: @tadman How can I check this? Sorry, I am a beginner to the rails environment.

Comment: You're going to have to look around and see which `twitter.rb` files you have present. The `find` command or even your Finder/Explorer can usually locate them quite easily. The gem itself will have one, plus possibly others if more than one copy of that gem is installed, such as different versions.

Comment: You can also do `$LOAD_PATH.map { |p| File.expand_path('twitter.rb', p) }.select { |p| File.exist?(p) }` to see what turns up.

Comment: @tadman Running that command returned an empty array

Comment: Through `irb` or through `rails c`? It should be done through the Rails console as that has all the load paths properly initialized. The ActiveSupport auto-loader might also latch on to any file called `twitter.rb` within your application, so search there as well.

Comment: Through `irb`. Doing so through `rails c` returns the `twitter.rb` from the gemfile:  `=> ["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter.rb"] `

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem outside of your Rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `irb` instead of the Rails console to run your code. When you run through `irb` (or `pry`), you aren't actually loading the Rails environment, so none of the gems will be available. You can manually require them, but you still won't have access to the Rails environment.

What you want to do instead is use `rails console` (or `rails c` for short).

For example with irb, Twitter isn't loaded:

```
rails_dir » irb
2.2.4 :001 > Twitter
NameError: uninitialized constant Twitter
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/bbugh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
```

With `rails c`, it works just fine:

```
rails_dir » rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.2.4 :001 > Twitter
=> Twitter
```

You can take all of those `require`s out of your initializer - Rails will require the gems automatically by that point. You just need to use `rails console` when you're doing console work with Rails.

Comment: Thank you for your help and feedback!